# The contents of the div not showing in print preview in safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I have a jsp which has some divs associated .These divs are populated with contents on runtime. After loading the contents, if i give self.print(), its showing the print preview, but no contents in the preview. This is happening in safari 7 whereas It works well in mozilla.
Can anybody help me?

Thanks,

Comment: Not an accurate answer, but it'd try `window.setTimeout(function() { self.focus();self.print(); }, 0);` at first.

Comment: It doesnt work for me....

Comment: Can somebody help me on this? still i am stuck up